# Meshing a smoke simulation

Tags: mesh, smoke-simulation

I have followed a tutorial on how to create explosions in Blender and now I want to export the explosion as OBJ. So for that I first need to create a mesh. I have seen multiple solutions, with using fluids or using the add-on CubeSurfer but nothing is working.

So how can I mesh my simulation or directly export it as OBJ. I am new to simulations in blender so a detailed answer would be very nice. I am working on 2.83

This is the blender file (this is a low quality example, so testing can be faster):

[image]

So thanks to vklidu I'm almost there, here is my current state, so that he can see what the problem is:

[image]

Comment: Are you able to provide a sample file for inspection? You may upload to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I personally would recommend sculpting a mesh using the smoke simulation as a reference, but I'll look into your problem to see if I can find an answer.

Comment: @Nate_Sycro27 Sculpting so many frames would take for ever and if I want to change something, I again would have much work

Comment: Oh, so you want to make the entire animation a mesh. I thought you meant just a single frame.

Comment: seems like duplication https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9421/export-a-smoke-simulation-as-a-mesh you could give a bounty to that thread. BTW do you have some reference of meshed smoke sim anim that satisfy your needs? Thank you

Comment: @vklidu That answer is not very detailed and I don't understand how to get the data to the mesh. I don't have any reference material, I just have seen a tutorial on how to create an explosion

Comment: You can change the cache type to final and set file format to OpenVDB and use the vdb files in the cache folder.

Comment: @Bruk ok and now what should I do with the vdb files?

Comment: vdb files are supported by many applications if why you want to export the simulation is to use it in another application use them in your app.

Comment: vdb files are supported by many applications if why you want to export the simulation is to use it in another application use them in your app.

Comment: @Bruk my application only supports OBJ and Blender can't open those vdb files either. What application can I use to import this?

Comment: I will try to write answer tomorrow, but meshed smoke would be far from something similar to smoke so I'm interested what is your visual goal to end up. It wouldn't be enough detailed or too heavy. Or are you looking for something stylized as pixel art?

Comment: @vklidu Thanks for you trying to write an answer, I don't really have smoke, since this is an explosion, so I have something like clouds. The voxel preview from blender looks good and probably is the only thing I can afford to render, since I want to use it in a real time application.

Comment: I happened across some openvdb python libraries here : https://www.openvdb.org/documentation/doxygen/python.html
As Blender 2.83 supports output of smoke and fluid domains to VDB files this should make it possible to write a Python script to convert a frame into a mesh by placing metaballs as for @vklidu's answer - or to create the geometry directly. I don't know how this would be animated (I guess it would be possibly to create shape keys to produce the animation...).

Comment: @RichSedman that sounds interesting, I don't really get what you want to do. Do you want to export the data as VDB and then use Python to convert it to a mesh or do you want to use metaballs? I'm programming in C++, but never used Python and I really don't have any experience with integrating python into blender, so you have to explain very detailed.

Comment: I guess Metaballs is the simplest solution as it's just a matter of placing them and Blender will build the geometry around it. Downside is that it's probably the most CPU intensive since metaballs are more heavyweight than just creating geometry (such as the faces of a cube around each edge voxel). I've done some work previously on rendering volumes and created an add-on to convert a Blender pointcache into images. I suspect that code may be a good start point to create mesh instead of images. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/149696/29586.

Comment: With a C++ background it shouldn't be too much of a leap to move into Python - a lot of the principles are very similar.

Comment: @RichSedman ok, so can you give me some code?

Comment: I can, but it’ll probably take some time. Also, the code I already have to read the smoke domain relies on Pointcache format - so it won’t work with later Blender versions without additional work. Actually, looks like Leander has got this one pretty much nailed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For python coders, I will add an answer demonstrating the python access to the smoke system.

The simulated smoke is stored in the modifier.

1. Access the correct modifier of the smoke domain object.
2. Go to its `domain_settings`.
3. The data is stored in a uniform grid, the resolution sets the divisions for the longest dimension.
4. It has the properties `density_grid`, `flame_grid`, `color_grid`. The first two are flat lists, which you can arange in an zyx grid. The `color_grid` has an additional dimension for rgba values.

I would suggest storing these values in vertex colors.

For further processing I would suggest the remesh modifier and the color transfer using Animation Nodes.

[image][image]

### Example Usage

You can grab the script (also included in the blend) from [github](https://github.com/LeanderSilur/Blender-Tools/blob/master/smoke/mesh_from_smoke.py). To use the script you have to setup your file first, as the script makes assumptions about the existence of some object.

1. Create a cube-shaped (equal dimensions!) domain object and name it ***domain***.
2. Add other inflow/outflow/obstacle objects and **bake the simulation**.
3. Create a collection named *simulated*. For our convenience, the script will place the created geometry there.
4. Open a Text Editor in a Blender area and copy-paste the script into a new textblock. With the script textblock open, go to the text editors menu and selected *Text > Run Script*. If the script runs correctly, mesh objects are placed in the *simulated* collection.

[image]

**Running the script in the example file will immediately crash Blender if you haven't baked the simulation yet.**

Follow these steps to test the example file.

1. Go into solid viewport mode. Unhide the *Collection* and select the smoke *domain* object.
2. Rebake the simulation under Physics Properties > Fluid (Domain) > Settings > Free Data + Bake.
3. Open the console for logging.
4. Run the script via Text > Run Script. When running the script, both **collections** have to be **active and visible** and the smoke simulation **cached**.

### Step By Step Explanation

The first step of a python script is to import so-called modules. These modules provide functionality, which python can access. The `bpy` module contains functionality to access Blenders data. `bmesh` is a representation of mesh objects. `numpy` is a library to manipulate numbers and in ours case matrices. The result of the smoke simulation is stored in a grid, which `numpy` can easily manipulate.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
import numpy as np
import mathutils
```

Next, I add a utility function. This functions receives a `string` *name* as a parameter and returns an object of that name. If the object doesn't exist yet, it creates a new mesh-object. If it exists it returns the same mesh object. With this helper function we can run the meshing function multiple times and simply overwrite our created objects without creating additional *object.001* each time.

```
def get_mesh(name):
    if bpy.data.objects.get(name) == None:
        me = bpy.data.meshes.new(name)
        bpy.data.objects.new( name, me )
    return bpy.data.objects[name]
```

Now come the main method, which gets the smoke simulation and accesses its properties on the current frame. The result gets written into a bmesh (Blenders module for mesh representation and manipulation).

The function definition start with `def` in python.

```
def write_smoke_to_bm(smoke_obj, bm):
```

I'm assuming that the smoke modifier is the first (with the index 0) modifier in the modifier stack *modifiers*. If it wasn't the index has to be adjusted. The modifiers has a property called *domain_settings*, which contains the domain settings of the smoke simulation.

```
    smoke_domain_mod = smoke_obj.modifiers[0]
    settings = smoke_domain_mod.domain_settings
```

The `domain_settings` object has the properties `resolution_max`, `density_grid`, `color_grid` and `flame_grid`. The first is simply the grid resolution which we set in the domain settings. We need to know this, because the voxel data is stored in a grid with this resolution. To simplify the matter, I restricted the domain object to uniform dimensions (as mentioned earlier) which result in a three-dimensional grid with `resolution_max` slots for each axis (x, y, z). The other objects are data object in the form of the grid. However, this data is stored in a long list, which we have to manually convert to a grid form. Converting it is optional, but very helpful. It is much more convenient to access the grid position with x, y, z coordinates instead of the nth position in a long list. This is were the `numpy` library comes in handy, because it can "reshape" the list into a 3 dimensional list. The `density_grid` and `flame_grid` are simply three dimensional grid now with a number representing the amount of density/flame.

Since we only want to add geometry where the density is high enough, I defined a density threshold (`thres`), which is a fourth of the highest density value in the whole grid.

```
    res = settings.resolution_max
    grid_density = np.array(settings.density_grid).reshape((res, res, res))
    grid_col = np.array(settings.color_grid).reshape((res, res, res, 4))
    grid_flame = np.array(settings.flame_grid).reshape((res, res, res))
    thres = np.max(grid_density)/4
```

Now, we construct a bounding box of the dimensions. Using `numpy again`, we can story the values of all the vertices of the smoke object (`smoke_obj`) in a matrix and extract the smallest and highest values of the vertices' coordinates for each of their axes. The variable `minmax` stores them as [[x_min, y_min, z_min], [x_max, y_max, z_max]].

In the same manner, we can calculated the step size of a single voxel. Since the number of steps is defined by the resolution_max, the size of the voxel (along the x axis for example) can be defined as `(x_max - x_min) / resolution_max`.

```
    verts = np.array([smoke_obj.matrix_world @ v.co for v in smoke_obj.data.vertices])
    verts = verts.reshape((*verts.shape, 1))
    minmax = np.stack((np.min(verts, axis=0), np.max(verts, axis=0)))
    minmax = np.reshape(minmax, minmax.shape[:2])

    step = (minmax[1] - minmax[0]) / res
```

The `bmesh` object, which we passed as a parameter to the function, story vertex colors in `loops`, which are the *vertices of a single face*. Since the vertex color layers probably don't exist, we can create them.

```
    density = bm.loops.layers.color.new("density")
    color = bm.loops.layers.color.new("color")
    flame = bm.loops.layers.color.new("flame")
```

In the next step we loop through the slot of the three-dimensional density grid (or `numpy`-matrix).

```
    for z in range(0, grid_density.shape[0]):
        for y in range(0, grid_density.shape[1]):
            for x in range(0, grid_density.shape[2]):
```

Then we check if this position in the grid is dense enough to "mesh" it. We use the threshold, which we defined earlier.

```
                if grid_density[z, y, x] > thres:
```

If it is dense enough, we can place a cube there. Or a sphere, or a single face or anything else. I use a cube, because there is a simple builtin function in the `bmesh` module: `create_cube`.

To properly position this cube, we have to supply it with the translation and scale in form of a matrix. Blenders `mathutils` method provides functions which can generate a matrix from translation and scale values.

```
                    mat = mathutils.Matrix.Translation((
                        minmax[0][0] + (x + 0.5) * step[0],
                        minmax[0][1] + (y + 0.5) * step[1],
                        minmax[0][2] + (z + 0.5) * step[2]
                    )).to_4x4()
                    mat = mat @ mathutils.Matrix.Diagonal(step * 0.95).to_4x4()
                        
                    verts = bmesh.ops.create_cube(bm, size=1, matrix=mat)['verts']
```

The `create_cube` function returns a dictionary object with an entry for the created vertices. Let's get the linked faces of those vertices.

```
                    faces = set()
                    for v in verts:
                        for face in v.link_faces:
                            faces.add(face)
```

Once we have the faces, we get the linked loops (think face corners) and assign their vertex-color layers (which we created earlier) the respective values. The density layer gets the density value, the color layer gets the color value and the flame layer gets the flame value. In the cases of the color layer we can simply assign the color rgba values at that slot to the loop. But in the cases of the density and flame we only have one value. That's why we use the python syntax of `[density_value] * 4` to create an rgba value as well to store in the vertex color layer: e.g. `1.2 => [1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2]`.

```
                    for face in faces:
                        for loop in face.loops:
                            loop[density] = [grid_density[z, y, x]] * 4
                            loop[color] = grid_col[z, y, x]
                            loop[flame] = [grid_flame[z, y, x]] * 4
```

This is the end of the function, which adds the geometry to a bmesh.

Now you can loop over all of the frames and create an object with the previous function.

Since we will have to do this for each frame individually, I will first gather a list of frames. The list of frames is defined by the cache start and end of the smoke domain object.

```
domain = bpy.data.objects['domain']
smoke = domain.modifiers[0]

depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
smoke_obj = domain.evaluated_get(depsgraph)
smoke_domain_mod = smoke_obj.modifiers[0]
settings = smoke_domain_mod.domain_settings
```

Just as before, this was the same code to get to the smoke domain settings, which store the properties `cache_frame_start` and `cache_frame_end`.

To organize our Blender file, the created objects are best placed in their own collection: *simulated*. Let's get a reference to that as well.

```
objects = bpy.data.collections['simulated'].objects
```

Now we can loop through all the frames. Since Blender becomes unresponsive for the duration of the execution of a python script, it is helpful to open the blender console (`Window > Open Console`) and print the current frames, which Blender is working on. `frame_set` advances the scene to a given frame and updates the objects and the smoke simulation state.

```
for frame in range(settings.cache_frame_start, settings.cache_frame_end):
    print(frame)
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame)
```

Get the current smoke simulation frame with the evaluated dependency graph.

```
    depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
    smoke_obj = domain.evaluated_get(depsgraph)
```

Create a new bmesh to hold the smoke mesh data for this frame. Then pass it to the function, which we wrote ealier.

```
    bm = bmesh.new()
    write_smoke_to_bm(smoke_obj, bm)
```

Using the helper function (also from above), we can create/get an object named *simulated##*, where ## stands for the current frame number. We write the bmesh data into that objects mesh and free the bmesh.

```
    ob = get_mesh('simulated' + str(frame).zfill(2))
    bm.to_mesh(ob.data)
    bm.free()
```

If the frame mesh object didn't exist, it would have been created. For that case, we have to move it into the *simulated* collections objects "list".

```
    try:
        objects.link(ob)
    except:
        pass # already in collection
```

If you were to execute the code uptill now, all mesh objects would be created and visible at once. This could be useful if you want to modify them further, etc. If you want to judge the playback however, you would rather only see the mesh object, which corresponds to the current frame. To achieve this, you can keyframe the visibility property of objects with the function `keyframe_insert`.

```
    for i in (frame - 1, frame + 1):
        ob.hide_viewport = ob.hide_render = True
        ob.keyframe_insert('hide_viewport', frame=i)
        ob.keyframe_insert('hide_render', frame=i)
    ob.hide_viewport = ob.hide_render = False
    ob.keyframe_insert('hide_viewport', frame=frame)
    ob.keyframe_insert('hide_render', frame=frame)
```

If you want to see any colors, set the viewport to vertex color mode or link the objects to a material, which uses the vertex colors we created.

[image: material settings]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109502/discussion-on-answer-by-leander-meshing-a-smoke-simulation).

Answer (score 5):

*Sorry, my post covers generating smoke as a single mesh in Blender 2.79, and not an entire smoke sim anim, due a buggy particle system (or smoke cache).*

*Blender 2.83 doesnt have texture type **Voxel Data**, but there is a **Voxel Mesher Modifier** on the way https://developer.blender.org/D4960*

---

In meantime my goal with 2.79 was to ...

- use voxel data to generate particle cloud from texture (01) or vertex weight (02)
- particles represent by metaballs
- animation export as Alembic or Wavefront, that converts metaballs (smoke) into Mesh Sequence animation

---

### test 01 - Mesh from Voxel Data Texture

Blender 2.79 contains texture type **Voxel Data** that use this kind of data as 3D texture. [Blender Manual describes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/blender_render/textures/types/volume/voxel_data.html) this quite straight forward. And it works for *8-bit RAW* and *Image Sequence* file format (like CT scan or MRI).

[image]

It means - it is possible (with some headaches*) to generate mesh from particle system represented by metaball objects, like this ...
[image]

Troubles comes with voxel file format **Smoke** (that should be able to reuse data of existing Smoke Domain on another object) and **Blender Voxel** (that should use externally saved simulation bake) ...
[image]
... I could see Material Preview in Texture Properties, but nothing was rendered.

Usage of these baked smoke simulations (externally) is buggy for years. Smoke doesn't appear in domain at all / or is shifted / or just a few frames of sim is visible. Not always, and that it makes more difficult to hunt issue. (One for all [bug report here](https://developer.blender.org/T40820) - as many of them were closed/archived.)

Anyway ... for your needs, when I assigned particle system directly to domain and Domain was set as Texture for particle density I was able to generate a particle cloud and to mesh one frame of smoke, but not entire animation. Probably for the reason mentioned above - bug. I'm not sure how  that one frame is selected, probably current frame set on timeline when assigned? Can't confirm due the refresh issue.

---

For those interested - in case smoke sim is baked ...

- add Metaball object
- select Smoke Domain
- add Particle system - Emission>Start1 End1 / Source>Volume / Distribution>Grid> / Velocity>zero / Texture>New (**Cycles only**) / Field Weight>Gravity=zero
- go to Texture (Particles) Properties - Type>Voxel Data / Voxel Data>Smoke / Color>Ramp=ON to adjust density / Influence>Density=ON

[image]

- set render particles as Object>Mbals
- export (Mball) as Wavefront(.obj) or Alembic (.abc) that converts metaballs into Mesh Sequence animation
- (in case someone will fix the bug :) )

[image]
[image]

[image]

---

*... another pain as hell is particle system refreshing https://developer.blender.org/T52160 . Even you have visible particle cloud, opening file again hides the particles. To make them visible again I discovered only one weird way - switch to Blender Internal engine into RenderView mode in 3Dview, change particle resolution to something, it refresh particle appearance, switch back to Cycles if needed.*

---

### test02 - Mesh from Dynamic Paint - Weight

Dynamic Paint in [video of Miikah](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DjL1KluUE-gU&psig=AOvVaw0S5MJBZOGJq6HRPsEg-pqq&ust=1592254996289000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA0QjhxqFwoTCPCEwJ6aguoCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD) can use a smoke sim as a "brush" to paint, so I wanted Weight paint into a dense grid using voxel data. Vertex Weight becomes Particle size solver. But ... I don't even thing this was implemented or I do something wrong here.
(I could only approved dynamic paint vertex-weight can generate animated particle cloud, but not driven by smoke.)

---

Resume - faked Fluid Particles seems to be a way to go ... :(

---

### Notes to fix setup of your second blend file

(this part I will delete later)

**Particle System Properties**

- Influence > enable Density
- Field Weights > Gravity = 0
- Render > Size is very small, try 0.4
- looks better to use Random for Emission>Grid

**Texture (Particles) Properties**

- Color > enable Ramp and move White to left to increase smoke density

**Mball Properties**

- keep in mind all metaballs in a scene use resolution from first existing meta object in a scene (doesn't matter what other meta objects are set). That means - lowres for Preview and small particle size value make them invisible for its low res grid.

**Time range**

- you have set Smoke cache frame range 1-90 even scene is set 1-150
- also particles system *Life Time* is only 50 should be 150

Screens below use – Grid Res 200 / Particle Size 0.1 / Mball Preview 0.2

Smoke Default Preview
[image]
Smoke Viewports Display Color Ramp
[image]
Mball Particles
[image]

Hight Grid Resolution + Smaller Particle Size + Smaller Metaballs resolution = More detailed final mesh

Bake smoke sim first. If particles are not visible check italic paragraph under my first blend file.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't understand much, where is this voxel data setting?

Comment: Thank you very much for investing so much time in this question, lets hope you can find something!

Comment: Your new answer looks very promising, where is `go to Particle Texture Properties - Type>Voxel Data / Voxel Data>Smoke / Influence>Density`  I couldn't find it

Comment: I wasn't aware that this also requires 2.79, so I remade it in 79, but it doesn't work, there are some particles of the meta ball but they are nowhere on the particles of the explosion. I added the blend file so maybe you can see what's wrong

Comment: Ok, I still wasn't able to get your result, so let's scrap this idea, since it won't work anyways. How does your fake method work?

Comment: When I asked devs, Brecht direct me to this link https://developer.blender.org/D4960 it is a patch of a new modifier "Voxel Mesher" that could be implemented quite soon.

Comment: Interesting, is there a way to install this future feature?