# Export to GLTF/GLB - Remove domain / bounding box from animation

Tags: animation, gltf

I am trying to export a 3D model with an animation as a `.glb` file, but the bounding box is obscuring the entire animation. Any way to remove the bounding box to show the actual animation?

Here is what I want exported: [image]

But this is what I get:

[image]

Comment: You'll need to provide more information to get help with this question. The glTF addon doesn't create arbitrary bounding boxes — something in your Blender scene is creating this box. If you can't find and hide it in Blender, you'd need to share details (the `.blend` file?) so that others can reproduce and debug.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Thank you for your reply! I have updated the original post with more information, please let me know if this helps!

Comment: Sorry, I still don't know what it is that you're exporting. Can you share enough information that someone could reproduce the problem you are seeing?

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Thanks for the response, I would have responded earlier but I didn't get an email or anything from StackExchange :/ So what I'm doing is basically creating a flame animation that comes out from an object, and I want to export it such that the flame animation will be attached to the `.glb` object. The smoke effect is coming from "Quick Smoke," from Quick Effects list in Blender 2.8

Comment: I don't think the "Quick Smoke" effect can be exported out of Blender. The types of animation that are portable to other software are typically: keyframe animation, armature/skinning, and morph targets / shape keys. You might be able to create a sequence of shape keys from a sequence of meshes by following https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9421/export-a-smoke-simulation-as-a-mesh.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Thank you so much! I'll give this a shot. I appreciate it!

Comment: @DonMcCurdy The problem still seems to persist with the liquid effect, as per the discussion in the link :( The issue is the entire bounding/domain box of the effect is being rendered, obscuring the actual frame(s) of the animation.

Comment: The box is not obscuring the animation — the shape of the volume is the only exportable part of the effect. Try zooming in through the box and you won't see a smoke effect inside.  You'll need to convert the effect to a mesh before exporting, which is (AFAIK) possible with liquid simulations but not Quick Smoke.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Okay thank you! I'll try this and get back to you. I appreciate all your responses!

Comment: @DonMcCurdy I'm still getting the bounding box issue, even with a fluid / mesh layout. Here are a few screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/Ap9HgHT

Comment: It may be easier to open a ticket on https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO with the `.blend` attached. In the screenshot above I assume something else in the scene is being exported as a cube, but I couldn't tell you which.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Okay I'll go ahead and open a ticket. Right now it's just my object with the liquid coming out, and the bounding box is for the fluid, which takes up most of the image.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy I found my solution! So when exporting, I needed to have these specific options checked while exporting: Include > Selected Properties / Custom Properties, Geometry > Apply Modifiers, Animation > Use Current Frame

https://imgur.com/aggINok